# Detect Mouse Hover Over Button?

Tags: c++, winapi, ownerdrawn

I have an owner-drawn button that I would like to highlight, when the mouse hovers over it.  Here is the simplified code, that doesn't seem to work:

```
case WM_DRAWITEM:
     LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT  pDraw = (LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT)lParam;
     if(pDraw->itemState == ODS_HOTLIGHT)  DrawButton(pDraw->hDC, HIcolor);
     else                                  DrawButton(pDraw->hDC, normcolor);
     return 0;
```

`DrawButton` is a custom function that draws the button.  The second parameter of this function is the primary color of the button.  The function has no trouble drawing the button.  The problem in in detecting the "item state".

I have also tried using `if(pDraw->itemState & ODS_HOTLIGHT)`.  That does not work either.

Obviously, I am missing something.  In my search, I have come across many answers.  However, *none* of them are in C++.

Comment: `pDraw->itemState & ODS_HOTLIGHT` is the only right check, not `==`. Try to ensure that you really receive this state message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ODS_HOTLIGHT` may not be used by the button. See *[What states are possible in a DRAWITEMSTRUCT structure?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20141211-00/?p=43423)*.

You can use [subclassing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/subclassing-overview), and then use [`TrackMouseEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-trackmouseevent) to get the event in [`SUBCLASSPROC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nc-commctrl-subclassproc).

```
LRESULT CALLBACK Subclassproc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    if (uMsg == WM_MOUSEMOVE)
    {
        TRACKMOUSEEVENT ev = {};
        ev.cbSize = sizeof(TRACKMOUSEEVENT);
        ev.dwFlags = TME_HOVER | TME_LEAVE;
        ev.hwndTrack = hWnd;
        ev.dwHoverTime = HOVER_DEFAULT;
        TrackMouseEvent(&ev);
    }
    else if (uMsg == WM_MOUSEHOVER)
    {
        RECT rc = {};
        GetClientRect(hWnd, &rc);
        HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
        SetDCBrushColor(hdc, RGB(255, 0, 0));

        SelectObject(hdc, GetStockObject(DC_BRUSH));

        RoundRect(hdc, rc.left, rc.top,
            rc.right, rc.bottom, 0, 0);
    }
    else if (uMsg == WM_MOUSELEAVE)
    {
        RECT rc = {};
        GetClientRect(hWnd, &rc);
        HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
        SetDCBrushColor(hdc, RGB(0, 255, 0));

        SelectObject(hdc, GetStockObject(DC_BRUSH));

        RoundRect(hdc, rc.left, rc.top,
            rc.right, rc.bottom, 0, 0);
        TRACKMOUSEEVENT ev = {};
        ev.cbSize = sizeof(TRACKMOUSEEVENT);
        ev.dwFlags = TME_HOVER | TME_LEAVE | TME_CANCEL;
        ev.hwndTrack = hWnd;
        ev.dwHoverTime = HOVER_DEFAULT;
        TrackMouseEvent(&ev);
    }
    return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}


    ...
    HWND hButton = CreateWindow(L"BUTTON", L"", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE |
        BS_OWNERDRAW, 10, 10, 60, 30, hWnd,
        (HMENU)10001, hInst, NULL);

    SetWindowSubclass(hButton, Subclassproc, 101, 0);
```

Comment: Thank you Drake Wu, for that very informative code and description.  I just have one question/clarification.  In `CreateWindow`, you assign an ID of "10001".  However, when setting the subclass, you use the number "101".  Is this a typo?  Or, are these two different numbers?

Comment: These are two different values. 10001 specifies `hMenu`, which can be used to receive click notifications(WM_COMMAND=>wParam), and 101 specifies subclassid, which can be used for subclass function like [`RemoveWindowSubclass`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-removewindowsubclass)

Comment: Thanks.  I see the difference.  As an alternate question, can the **same** number be used in both instances.  Or, would this cause a conflict?

Comment: No. At least the sample I used did not conflict. These two instances represent different meanings, and you can use the same value.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [the description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-drawitemstruct) of the `ODS_HOTLIGHT` value:

> ODS_HOTLIGHT: The item is being hot-tracked, that is, the item will be highlighted when the mouse is on the item.

So, I suppose that in order to receive this message you need to use the [`TrackMouseEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-trackmouseevent) function first.