# Properly handling owner drawn Win32 button hovering

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to add multiple color themes to my Win32 application, this means that I have to manually handle all the control drawing manually by using the `BS_OWNERDRAW` style flag. I then handle all the drawing in the `WM_DRAWITEM` message through the `LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT` structure stored in the `lParam`. Here's the problem though, by introducing owner drawing I also have to handle click and hover events, which in and of itself isn't a problem but it becomes one because it turns out that the `LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT` has no message being sent to indicate whether or not a control is being hovered. The `itemState` member do have messages like `ODS_SELECTED`, `ODS_FOCUS` and so on, but no flag for hovering only.

That being said, there does exist a flag named `ODS_HOTLIGHT` which according to MSDN should do the job, the problem however is that this flag **never** occurs for buttons, only menu items. I've tried using the `SetWindowSubclass` function by giving each control it's separate WindowProc callback where you can track the mouse leaving and entering the control. This works, but that also means that I need to transition all drawing commands over to the subclass procedure, which seems rather stupid to me, since the `WM_DRAWITEM` is *intended for custom drawing in the first place*.

You could always send `WM_DRAWITEM` manually via `SendMessage` but that also means that I need to provide an `LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT` *manually* which hasn't worked out that great. In essence I do not know what the best approach is to react to these hover events and draw them accordingly, the `LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT` does not provide such a flag and thus I have no idea what other approach to use. How should I tackle this?

**The way I'm currently handling the `WM_DRAWITEM` message (buttons only):**

```
case WM_DRAWITEM: {
  LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT pDIS = (LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT)lParam;
  HPEN borderPen = CreatePen(PS_INSIDEFRAME, 0, RGB(0, 0, 0));
  HGDIOBJ oldPen = SelectObject(pDIS->hDC, borderPen);
  HGDIOBJ oldBrush;

  if (pDIS->itemState & ODS_SELECTED) {
    oldBrush = SelectObject(pDIS->hDC, buttonHoverBrush);
  }
  else {
    oldBrush = SelectObject(pDIS->hDC, buttonDefaultBrush);
  }

  // Rounded button
  RoundRect(pDIS->hDC, pDIS->rcItem.left, pDIS->rcItem.top, pDIS->rcItem.right, pDIS->rcItem.bottom, 5, 5);

  //Clean up
  SelectObject(pDIS->hDC, oldPen);
  SelectObject(pDIS->hDC, oldBrush);
  DeleteObject(borderPen);

  // Calculate button dimensions
  int buttonWidth = pDIS->rcItem.right - pDIS->rcItem.left;
  int buttonHeight = pDIS->rcItem.bottom - pDIS->rcItem.top;

  WCHAR staticText[128];
  int len = SendMessage(pDIS->hwndItem, WM_GETTEXT, ARRAYSIZE(staticText), (LPARAM)staticText);
  HFONT buttonFont = (HFONT)SendMessage(pDIS->hwndItem, WM_GETFONT, 0, 0);

  SIZE buttonDim;
  HFONT oldFont = (HFONT)SelectObject(pDIS->hDC, buttonFont);
  GetTextExtentPoint32(pDIS->hDC, staticText, len, &buttonDim);

  SetTextColor(pDIS->hDC, RGB(255, 255, 255));
  SetBkMode(pDIS->hDC, TRANSPARENT);
  TextOut(pDIS->hDC, buttonWidth / 2 - buttonDim.cx / 2, buttonHeight / 2 - buttonDim.cy / 2, staticText, len);

  wasHandled = TRUE;
  result = TRUE;
  break;
}
```

The code listed above creates a button with a given background color and centers text within it. It also changes color to the hover rush when clicked. What I want to happen is that the button changes its color immediately **upon hover** and not upon click. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Related/dupe: [Detect Mouse Hover Over Button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65281372/)

Comment: You could try just checking the cursor position inside your painting code. If the button gets redrawn automatically when you move the mouse over it that should work I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've tried using the `SetWindowSubclass` function by giving each control it's separate `WindowProc` callback where you can track the mouse leaving and entering the control. This works, but that also means that I need to transition all drawing commands over to the subclass procedure, which seems rather stupid to me, since the `WM_DRAWITEM` is *intended for custom drawing in the first place*.

Unfortunately, that is precisely what you will likely need to do.

For instance, you can have the button's subclass procedure handle the `WM_MOUSEMOVE` message to detect when the mouse is over the button, and handle the `WM_MOUSELEAVE` message to detect when the mouse moves out of the button.  The message handler can use `WM_MOUSEMOVE` to call `TrackMouseEvent()` to trigger `WM_MOUSELEAVE` and `WM_MOUSEHOVER` messages.  It can then use `WM_MOUSEHOVER` to set a flag and invalidate the button to trigger a repaint, and it can use `WM_MOUSELEAVE` to clear the flag and invalidate the button to trigger a repaint.

Inside the button's normal draw handler (which DOES NOT need to be moved to the subclass procedure. BTW), if the flag is set then draw the button as hovered, otherwise draw it as non-hovered.

The only gotcha with this approach is if you have multiple buttons then you will need multiple flags, one per button.  But you can use `(Get|Set)WindowLongPtr(GWL_USERDATA)` or `(Get|Set)Prop()` to store/retrieve each button's flag inside/from the button's `HWND` directly  Or, you can just maintain your own `std::map` (or other lookup table) of `HWND`-to-flag associations.

Another option would be to have the subclass procedure use the `WM_MOUSE(MOVE|HOVER|LEAVE)` messages to send simulated `WM_DRAWITEM` messages to the button, specifying/omitting the `ODS_HOTLIGHT` style as needed so the drawing code can look for that style.  You might need the subclass procedure to intercept `WM_PAINT` messages to make that work, though.  Not sure about that.

Otherwise, you could simply have your `WM_DRAWITEM` handler grab the mouse's current coordinates and see if they fall within the button's client area, and then draw accordingly.

Comment: Very elegant solution, didn't even think about storing it in the ```GWLP_USERDATA``` index. However, when you say "Inside the button's normal draw handler", where would this be? By subclassing the buttons I lose all control on related WM_PAINT and etcetera, right?

Comment: "*when you say "Inside the button's normal draw handler", where would this be?*" - in your `WM_DRAWITEM` handler. "*By subclassing the buttons I lose all control on related WM_PAINT and etcetera, right?*" - no. The subclass would receive all messages first, but passing any message to `DefSubclassProc()` will send it to the previous pre-subclassed message procedure for default processing.

Comment: @JackHenrikson maybe you missed by latest update, but I already included that in my answer: "*It can then use **`WM_MOUSEHOVER`** to set a flag and invalidate the button to trigger a repaint...*"